# Music sharing server with Web portal

Tags: web-apps, music, windows-10, web-server, self-hosted

I am looking for server software to share/host my music.

#### Must haves:

- HTTP Web portal
- Ability to upload files and folders
- Ability to download songs individually or en mass
- Must run on Windows 10
- Free

#### Nice to haves:

- Ability to play music from the Web interface
- Client software

**Similar programs** that don't quite make the cut:

- [Orb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb_(software)), discontinued
- [Jinzora](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jinzora/), complicated
- [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/), no multi-file download capability

Comment: A notable project but does not allow uploading/downloading files is [koel](http://koel.phanan.net)

Comment: You want to host the server on your Windows 10 machine, correct? For which operating system(s) should the (nice to have) client software be?

Comment: @unor As i said, It must have an HTTP portal so client software is semi-irrelivent. But, if it has client software, it should work on at least Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend ownCloud. It meets all your requirements including having an HTTP Web Portal, uploading files, downloading file(s), compatible with Windows 10 (written in PHP), and being open source. It also allows an extension where it can play music within the browser and has client software that allows you to sync your music between the server and your computer.

Note: You must use version 7 of ownCloud as version 8+ is no longer supported in Windows. Version 7 does still meet the requirements of the OP's question.

## [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) ([open source](https://github.com/owncloud))

> ownCloud gives you web services under your control. It is a self-hosted open source platform with file sync and sharing at its core and available clients for desktop and mobile. The web frontend has apps for Pictures, Calendar, Contacts, News/RSS, Bookmarks, Notes, Music and much more via an open app platform!
>
> ownCloud Server can be installed on Windows and Linux operating systems, and is available via packages, sources, or a one file php installer.
>
> [image: ownCloud Music UI]

Comment: ownCloud does not seem to natively work on Windows.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos ownCloud is written in PHP which runs on Windows. I suggest finding a WAMP stack and then installing ownCloud through it.

Comment: ownCloud stopped supporting Windows as of v8.1

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Where on earth did you read this? I'm using the client of ownCloud on my Windows 10 64bit laptop and the ownCloud instance itself runs on PHP which runs practically anywhere.

Comment: Right on their site. https://owncloud.org/blog/owncloud-server-8-1-will-not-support-windows-as-server-platform-natively/

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Oh, I see, your a bit confused on what they're talking about (it's ok, they're not all that clear). What they mean by this is it's essentially a server image ready to go out of the box. Head over to their downloads section and click the "Download" button under "Get ownCloud Server". You'll see four different options/ways to install ownCloud. First is an archive file which is the one you want (get a WAMP stack and follow the install instructions - I am using this method now with [easyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) and it works great).

Comment: Just to go through the rest, the second option is the Web Installer which essentially downloads everything that the Archive File contains (but just wrapped up in one single PHP script). The third option is specifically for Linux (you can also install ownCloud as a package within Linux). The fourth and last option is an actual virtual image that works right out of the box. Again, if you use the Archive File and install it using a WAMP stack, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I'm installing WAMP now. Hopefully this will work

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos My gosh, it may not, in fact, be supported - I'm sorry, I'm using version 7.0 of ownCloud which is supported on Windows (tried to update and ran into a few issues). My apologies, this is quite annoying, to be honest, virtual machines (I'm looking into this further) do work though if you're interested in that and version 7.0 should have all the functionality your looking for too. Again, I was actually using ownCloud which is why I gave the response above. Again, sorry about that.

Comment: I have tried install twice, Failed both time. With a missing .dll and odd code. I think I should pursue another, more music focused, option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38991/discussion-between-tom-and-michelfrancis-bustillos).